# How to wildcard find images with jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is the scenario. I am using clolorbox. Currently I have it finding all a links within a parent container id to work the lightbox on. This is fine if all of those links are images. However, I am hoping to be able to restrict the a links to those that contain ONLY images. There will be a mix of image links and pdf and autocad files within the parent.  Ideally I need a way to wild card for .jpg and png to replace my find(a). My code at the moment is this:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('#documents-items').find('a').colorbox();
});
```

There will be no way for me to format any specific tables with a class or anything like that because the document manager is a module for DNN. I can grab the parent id though and hopefully wildcard the image links to make it work....

Thank you

Comment: Can you provide some sample markup? I just want to validate whether you are wanting to filter based on the `href` of the `<a>` or based on some child element of the `<a>`. Your line about "There will be a mix... within the parent" left me unsure. Both are certainly viable; the answer will simply differ based on the markup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
$('#documents-items a[href$=".jpg"]').add('#documents-items a[href$=".png"]')
```

Comment: Per the OP's question, if you do it this way, don't forget a `.add()` to also grab those anchors whose `href` ends in ".png"

Comment: +1 Nice use of the attribute selectors. @user45585 [Here](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/) is a complete list of jQuery's supported attribute selectors...

Comment: @Stevangelista thanks, didn't read that part changed the answer

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your HTML looks like this (DOM IDs generally don't contain dashes, so I replaced with an underscore):

```
<div id="document_items">
    <a href="index.html">HTML Link</a>
    <a href="document.pdf">PDF Link</a>
    <a href="image.png">Image Link</a>
    <a href="image.jpg">JPEG Link</a>
</div>
```

you can iterate through all the links in the `#document_items` selector and run a Regular Expression match on each resulting href attributes.

If it matches the required file extension in the link, you can attach colorbox to it, otherwise ignore it.

So your JavaScript will look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#document_items a").each(function() {
        var currentHref = $(this).attr("href");
        if (currentHref.match(/jpg$|png$/)) {
            $(this).colorbox();
        }
    });
});
```

Quick explanation about what's happening in the Regular Expression:

`/.../` = starts and ends the expression

`$` = end of the string

`|` = OR

So this matches the end of the href with jpg or png

Comment: An `.each()` iteration over all the anchors, plus use of `.match()` seem like expensive operations when a native jQ attribute selector would suffice.

Comment: The selected answer is elegant and definitely more performant.  Nice job Cass!